# Why this query to get friends is not returning any result?

Tags: sql

I have a table named friends which contains 3 columns:

```
user1id, user2id, status
```

`Status` is a foreign key to an another table `FriendshipStatuses` and both of the other columns are foreign keys to `user` table.

I tried some different queries which resulted in false and getting friendships that were still in request.The query I provided is returning no results.

`$userId` contains the current logged in user's id

```
SELECT
    users.username, 
    users.fullName, 
    users.user_id 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    users.user_id IN (SELECT user1id, user2id
                      WHERE user1id = $userId 
                         OR user2id = $userId)
```

Comment: What do you mean returning FALSE?  There's no FALSE in SQL.

Comment: I mean no results

Comment: I'm surprised your query even run.  `IN` only works in single column table.

Comment: Just checked some resources and learned more about IN me too but I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't do anything useful:

```
SELECT user1id, user2id 
WHERE user1id=$userId 
OR user2id = $userId
```

You're missing a `FROM` in this with a **table** or **view** that has columns `user1id` and `user2id`.

Comment: I think it should only be 1 column for the in clause.

Comment: Fixed, error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)